# Should I create a module per component in Angular 4+ app?

Tags: angular

We have a medium sized Angular 4 application (+-150 components).

Many of these components require the injection of service classes and require the declaration of other components in the app.

An approach we have been experimenting with, and have found to be much more developer friendly, is to create a module per component. The module imports the child component modules and provides (or imports) all the services needed by the component. It also exports the component itself so that other components can reference it through the module.

It makes the composition of components a breeze and the setup of the test fixture of a component very simple (this is where there was previously a lot of repetition of dependencies and child component tree dependencies).
This approach seems to match the component based architecture and allows for a form of encapsulation around what a components dependencies are.
It feels just too good to be true ;)

My question is, what is the performance (or other) impact of having so many modules?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. This approach brought our test run times down massively. From 2mins30sec for 700 tests to 5 seconds. Much less developer overhead ;-) Hmmm... not sure why my Question has been downvoted. Maybe it is a sign that others think it is a bad idea.

Comment: I actually think that is the way to do it, one module includes parent and child component, remember when angular was beta we could´t do this... and we had one module for huge apps, that was the opposite of friendly, not what Mark says

Comment: If you're developing a library, having a module per component is often the way to go. Check ng-bootstrap for example. If you're developing an app, it's better to group components by feature. _not sure why my Question has been downvoted._ - don't pay attention, this is the illness of SO

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com: If you're developing a library, having a module per component is often the way to go. Could you elaborate a bit more in why?

Comment: @Bob, a consumer of your library may choose to use only one component from your library and so it'd be convenient to import that component module instead of the entire lib module with multiple components.

Comment: From the [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#feature-modules): "Do create an NgModule for all distinct features in an application"

Comment: @MaxWizardK I actually got the idea from using a library ;-)  I ended up doing this in my app and saw purely benefits. The only thing I was concerned about was the performance impact of having many modules. I have heard that the concept of modules disappears when the app is compiled. Are you able to confirm this, given your AngularInDepth(TM) knowledge ;-)

Comment: @MarkWhitfeld, yes, they are all compiled and merged. you can [watch my talk at ngconf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pERhnBBae2k) or read [my article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f) on modules. ask questions if any :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I consider **one module per component** the best way to design your Angular apps.

If it depends on other components, you can include only the **component modules** related to each component that is a **direct dependency** and don't need to care about indirect dependencies.

It may seem more work at first, but it will pay you back will less maintenace problems.

If `ComponentA` depends on `ComponentB` that depends on `ComponentC` create a:

`ModuleC` related to `ComponentC`

`ModuleB` related to `ComponentB` that imports `ModuleC`

`ModuleA` related to `ComponentA` that imports `ModuleB` (it doesn't need to import directly `ModuleC`)

If `ComponentB` now depends on `ComponentD` (like including `<my-component-d>` in the template) and stops depending on `ComponentC` you just change `ModuleB` and all components that depend on `ComponentB` will work fine, if you are using this approach.

Think now about hundreds of components. How many components will depend on `ComponentB`?

I consider this problem similar with the old way (or not too old) of including js files in script tags:

```
<script src="build/a.js"></script>
<script src="build/b.js"></script>
<script src="build/c.js"></script>
```

And if you change `b` to stop depending on `c` and starts depending on `d`, all pages that import `b` have now to import `d`, and so on, leading to a maintenance nightmare. You may also forget to remove (the now unneeded) `c.js` and import it needlessly in some pages, increasing your boot time (**or worse**, you remove it from all files that import `b.js`, but some page imports `e.js` that depends on `c.js` and you break some functionality of that page).

Instead I consider it much better to import:

```
<script src="build/bundle.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="build/main.js"></script>
```

and the dependencies are handled by a module bundler, like `webpack`.

There is the approach of making a module with lots of components and just import it, but you end up importing several components **that you don't use** and if you use lazy loading, **your modules may become huge**, unless you import that module in AppModule, making your **boot time increase**.

You can still use the approach of one component per module **with feature modules**. Just import the **component module** into the feature module (instead of the component itself):

*feature.module.ts:*

```
imports: [
    ComponentAModule,
    ComponentBModule,
    ComponentCModule,
]
```

(You may want to export them too).

I also consider this approach the best way when creating libraries, otherwise you would **force the consumers** of the library **to import all the components**, even if they only use 1 or 2 components in the library.

I'm experiencing this issue with `ionic3`: the minified `ionic-angular` library has `437KB` of which `292KB` are the components (hopefully it will change with `ionic4`). I use just a few `ionic` components, there was no need to import all of them, **but I have no choice** (unless I fork the repo or stop using it).

I have an app with 176 components and this was the best approach in my opinion. Before, I included several components in a feature module and it gave me some headaches later on. Also, it was harder when changing a component from a feature module to another (**What about its dependencies? They were all mixed together**).

I haven't found a satisfactory approach with services (`@Injectable()`) tough.

In the end it's up to you the decision. This is my opinion based on my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lucas. Although this question is hugely subject to people's opinions around the structuring of their app given their context I do believe that this is a really good way to go. Having taken this approach in my app I have experienced all the benefits you mentioned. The small amount of work in creating a module per component definitely improves the maintainability and compose-ability of the app. Apparently the module construct disappears through compilation so it doesn't even add an overhead. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MarkWhitfeld Yes! In my case the biggest problem was the initial change from the monolitic modules with several components to one module per component, but now I only need to create new modules when I create new components, and the time it takes for creating the module is surely much less than it takes to create the component itself (with the logic and the template), so I see the module creation as part of the component creation, and now it's much easier to change dependencies among components and removed unused ones.

Comment: Would you use one module per @Pipe ?

Comment: @Yanal-YvesFargialla In the project I said above I'm using one module per pipe and it's working fine (I receive an error if the module isn't loaded, then I just include it and it works). But if your pipes will be, in most cases, small, and you will have just a few of them, then I think that it shouldn't be a big problem in importing every pipe in a single module (but if you don't know exactly how big the project will be, I think one module per component would be better). If you are creating a library, though, then one module per component should be the way to go.

Comment: @LucasBasquerotto, Thank you for your answer.
My Angular 7.x app uses lady loading and had a SharedModule containing shared components used across lazy loaded modules.
I have refactored the app and I have now one module per component for the shared components.
Before and after the refactor I ran `npm run aot`: the total size of chunks has decreased by 7.6%. 
So thank you for your advises :-)

Comment: @Yanal-YvesFargialla Cool! But the main reason is not even about the final bundle size, but the size that is loaded in the initial load (that affects the performance of the app at the startup). The less you have to load at the startup, the better. The ideal scenario is to only load what is really needed at the startup (although other modules could be loaded asynchronously, such as to not affect the initial load, but make lazy loaded modules start faster).

Comment: The idea of lazy loading is moot, most angular apps today load all at once, why, because of future techs like PWA which prefetch, even when this answer was written. I have also found the module structure to add significant overhead in load time since it adds anywhere up to 8kb after compilation to maintain a module. Also loading the way you show there would not actually lazy load the modules, you need to use import() to lazy load. The question here is: would eager loading all components into memory break the client device?

Comment: The problem you are getting with ionic is more about having to include entire external deps rather than the client's own problems with this, I think it is like comparing apples to oranges tbh

Comment: @Sammaye The OP question is if he should be using one module per component and the performance implications. Although each module add overhead, they would be scoped to the components that need to be loaded. If you intend to load everything at once, there's no need of one module per component, neither feature modules, but if your site gets really big, your users will suffer in the initial load, and even when cached, the javascript will need to be loaded in each page refresh.

Comment: The case where I consider that one module per component should always be used are in libraries, and the ionic was just one example of the problem that including everything in one module cause (in libraries). IMO libraries should not force the consumer to load everything, even what isn't used (unless it's a tiny library). On websites/webapps it's fine to include everything in one module if there's no perspective that it will grow too much.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add an answer since this appears as the first result for me on Google and I feel like I have something to impart to others after searching endlessly.

I have an application whereby all but one area is written as module per screen, not quite component but close.

I recently wanted to understand if lazy loaded modules really helped.

**Lazy loading**

Moot. Most Angular apps even when this question as asked use PWA or pre-fetching to ensure the user gets as much of the app asap and does not have their experience interrupted by broken bundles from updates to the delivery source, i.e. an S3 bucket proxied via CloudFront.

Also lazy loading is totally non existent if you do not use the import() function. So merely using the import property in another module to import other modules does not actually lazy load them.

**Bundle size**

No. Modules cost 8kb on average post compilation and I have calculated with 27 modules my app can use up to 556kb just to maintain this way of coding.

**Download time**

Again no. Lazy loaded module = bundle and bundle = thread to download bundle. In reality you want something whereby code is evenly spread but the files are not too big, max of 600kb each, this would be easily downloadable on slow 3G connections.

**Render time**

This heavily depends on the user device, I have no solid testing here, but even your average mobile phone could easily handle a large app so it can probably handle your app if it is under 100 components per bundle.

Also remember that a module IS in the file, it WILL be transcoded by the JS engine, and it WILL add weight to your app.

I actually did a test of 10 (yes, not super reliable but just a quick one) requests from a browser to two versions of the app, one with changes to add lazy modules to the last part of said app and without (no changes) and I found the one with changes returned slower more often than the one without. It was a close draw between the two on average but the one with more lazy loaded modules returned a bit slower more often.

**SOC**

Yes, but this is subjective to how the developer feels, some like SCAM, some like crazy paradigms that no one else understands, either way SOC can be achieved easily by sanely separating components into modules instead of making never ending nesting of folders and clicking through module includes.

**Conclusion**

So really I wouldn't believe what a lot of people tell you about using modules, you have to use your own decisions and weigh them up with the impact to the user.

You may find the best way is to find a middle ground between the two of organisation and performance.

As an update Angular now supports standalone components https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components and soon new Angular applications will be coded without the use of modules.