# Angular Modules: Circular Dependency

Tags: angular

I am refactoring my App to use one module for each component ([Should I create a module per component in Angular 4+ app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434830/should-i-create-a-module-per-component-in-angular-4-app)). The thing is, sometimes I have situations like this : `Component A` depends on `Component B`, and `Component B` depends on `Component A`. I know that I can create a module that wraps both of them, resolving the issue. But then there is no way to use the "one module for each component" approach anymore, or am I misunderstanding something?

I made a small application for testing it out:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zemrr4

From what I have seen is that there are three configurations, of which two do not work:

- Add `Component A` and `Component B` to a shared module (`app.module` in case of the example). This works, but gets rid of the modules for `Component A` and `Component B` respectively (which makes the "one module for each component" approach useless.)
- Add Module A and Module B to the shared module. This would be the desirable solution, but does not work, as the parent module does not emit the exports from `Module A` to `Module B` and vice versa. Here is where I start to fail to understand how exactly modules work, as I would expect that to be possible.
- Import `Module A` into `Module B`, and `Module B` into `Module A`. This creates a circular dependency and does not work.

What is the best practice for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly order your controllers and services to avoid circular dependencies.

In case of components if there are circular dependencies in modules, the you MUST sort your modules and generate new modules to avoid that. Also you should update your angular version with ng update command https://angular.io/cli/update and try stand alone components https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components if you don't want to generate lot of modules (inssist in sort app components architecture)

Anyways, to avoid that, you can try generating static methods to avoid constructor initializations (which may cause a circular dependency)

Or, remove the dependency of the constructor, and use environmentInjector (v15, named runInInjectionContext in v16 https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#runInInjectionContext)

Your service/component

```
import { EnvironmentInjector, inject } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
    private environmentInjector: EnvironmentInjector,
) { }

method(): void {
    this.environmentInjector.runInContext(() => {
        const yourService = inject(YourService);
        // execute the rest of the code
    });
}
```

But I would insist into sort the functionallity to avoid circular dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Circular references generally mean one of two things:

1. You have two bits of code that you think are separate, but are not.
2. You have three bits of code, and you chopped one of them into two pieces and put one piece next to bit A, and the other piece next to bit B.

I find #1 happening most often with newer developers who are trying to blindly adhere to some rule or another without really understanding the purpose behind it. Some things are inherently tightly coupled and trying to split them up is only going to create more work for no gain.

#2 happens for much the same reason. Library A gets written. Sometimes it's complete, sometimes not. Then Library B gets written and it definitely needs to use that function from `A`, so it takes it as a dependency.

But then in `B`, something clever gets done that could be used in `A`. But it doesn't belong in `A` because it's primarily used in `B`. What to do!? If you find yourself in this scenario, it's time to make `C`. `C` would be a common dependency for `A` and `B`. Now either one can be utilized in a project without the other one needing to be present.

Trying to keep dependencies small by only having one thing per module doesn't mean that having multiple small modules as dependencies for a given component is a bad thing.